# Adding parent name to boost ptree

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I have a boost ptree with nodes:

```
pt.put("a.b", 1.0);
pt.put("a.c", 2.0);
pt.put("b.g", 3.0);
```

I would like the extract a tree that has "a.b" and "a.c" (but not "b.g").  When I use pt.get_child("a") I get a tree with "b" and "c".  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe already works. See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d778a36993bccfc)**

If you want to filter out anything "non-a", just

- delete the other nodes <kbd>**[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f563adf1f90f52d9)**</kbd>

  ```
  for (auto it = pt.begin(); it != pt.end();)
  {
      if (it->first != "a")
          it = pt.erase(it);
      else
          ++it;
  }
  ```
- create a new tree <kbd>**[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/830718817fd1c78d)**</kbd>

  ```
  ptree pt2;
  pt2.add_child("a", pt.get_child("a"));
  ```